# Using auto-complete in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

I'm new to ruby on rails. In fact, I've started working on it from yesterday. All the concepts are new to me. I'm stuck with a problem which I need help for.

This is my controller file.

```
    class ProductsController < ApplicationController  
      def new
        #render :layout => 'mylayout'
      end

      def result 
        #@site_matches = Srch.find(:all,:conditions =>["q=?",params[:q]] ) 
        #render :layout => 'mylayout'
      end

      def show
        #render text: params[:products].inspect
        @site_matches = Srch.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:name]}%")
      end
    end
```

This is my HTML file where I receive my search word and display the result.

```
    <h1>Results for your search.</h1>
    <%= render "products/new"%>
<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Max. Price</th><th>Min. Price</th><th>Discount</th><th>Image</th></tr>

    <% for prod in @site_matches %>
    <tr><td><%= prod.name %></td><td><%= prod.maxprice%></td><td><%= prod.minprice%></td><td><%= prod.discount%></td><td> <%= image_tag(prod.image, :alt => "logo", :size => "75x75") %> </td></tr>

    <% end %>
    </table>
    </br>

    <%= link_to "Search again" , "new" %>
```

I'm able to fetch my data and show the results correctly. But I need to add auto-complete feature to this existing one. How could I do it 
i)without using sunspot and 
ii)also how to do it using sunspot?

Answer (score 0):

For auto complete you can use Jquery's auto complete utility all you have to do is to provide json data to auto complete. Rails have to_json function which convert your current result to json

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also try [Rails 3 Jquery Autocomplete Gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete), i always use it on my projects, it's customizable and easy to install.